# handling variable changes from a function and fixture.detectChanges()

Tags: angular

I have this simple component:

```js
class AppComponent extend Component {
  name = "";

  changeName(n){
    let that : any = this;
    this.updateStorage.setName(n).then(n=>{
      console.log(`new name is ${n}`);
      that.name = n;
    });

  }

}
```

Now the test is to make sure after calling changeName(), the name variable gets update. updateStorage() returns the name passed (console shows it). updateStorage() service simply writes to localStorage a bunch of stuff then spits out the provided name.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});


it("should update name", () => {
  //fixture.detectChanges()
  component.changeName("zebra");
  expect(component.name).toEqual("zebra");
});
```

but component.name is always empty. I am almost certain it is because the server is a promise and I am checking before it resolves. How do I go with the test?

Comment: Have you read Angular's guidance on testing async code, e.g. https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-fakeasync?

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe I didn't get it quite right but will try it again, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to have done it with (done). Perhaps a little verbose:

```
it(':', (done) => {
  let updateStorage = TestBed.get(UpdateStorage);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  let spy = spyOn(updateStorage, 'changeName').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve("n"));
 component.changeName("n");
  spy.calls.mostRecent().returnValue.then(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.name).toEqual("n");
    done();
  });
});
```